# Why TreeSet has a separate constructor for SortedSet when there is already one for any Collection?

Tags: java, data-structures, collections

Constructor for any Collection :
`public TreeSet(Collection<? extends E> c)`

Seperate constructor for SortedSet :
`public TreeSet(SortedSet<E> s)`

Why there is a need for a separate one for SortedSet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/TreeSet.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.util.SortedSet)) of the constructor that accepts a `SortedSet`:

> Constructs a new tree set containing the same elements and using the same ordering as the specified sorted set.

When initializing a `TreeSet` from a `Collection`, the natural ordering of the elements is used, as seen from the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/TreeSet.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.util.Collection)) of the other constructor that accepts a `Collection`:

> Constructs a new tree set containing the elements in the specified collection, sorted according to the *natural ordering* of its elements.

Comment: So if the collection is other than `SortedSet`, then it's ordering will be lost and will be sorted according to the natural ordering. And if it is a SortedSet then the sorting will remain the same as per its `Comparator`. Right?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

[TreeSet's doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html)

**`public TreeSet(Collection<? extends E> c)`**

> Constructs a new tree set containing the elements in the specified
>   collection, sorted according to the natural ordering of its elements.
>   All elements inserted into the set must implement the Comparable
>   interface. Furthermore, all such elements must be mutually comparable:
>   e1.compareTo(e2) must not throw a ClassCastException for any elements
>   e1 and e2 in the set.

Pay more attention at "**sorted according to the natural ordering of its elements**"

**`public TreeSet(SortedSet<E> s)`**

> Constructs a new tree set containing the same elements and using the
>   same ordering as the specified sorted set.

Answer (score 1):

Let's run this program with two different flavors,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<User> ul = new ArrayList<>();
    ul.add(new User());
    ul.add(new User());

    Set<User> users = new TreeSet<>(ul);
}
```

first with below (here we are implementing Comparator)

```
private static class User implements Comparator<User> {
    @Override
    public int compare(User o1, User o2) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

With this program, it throws *Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: test.WTest$User cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable*

Because this constructor expects the User to be implementing *java.util.Comparable* interface.

Second run, if you change the User class implementation to below

```
private static class User implements Comparable<User> {

    @Override
    public int compareTo(User o) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

The code runs just fine! Notice the difference in the implements, now we are implementing java.lang.Comparable interface.

But TreeSet class works with both, either with Comparator or Comparable. So the choice of the constructor purely depends on the type of implementation your object has.